# Django: ¿Cómo combino o concateno 2 campos de un modelo en mi queryset

Tags: django

Buenas:

Tengo un `queryset` de busquedas y a continuación deseo juntar estos 2 campos d `chofer__segundo_apellido__icontains` y `chofer__primer_apellido__icontains`, ahora mismo el usuario pueda buscar por el primer apellido, tanto como el segundo apellido, pero que pasa si existen 40 personas que tienen ese mismo apellido(sé que es exagerado, pero bueno es lo que piden) ... 
Cómo concateno o hago el junte de estos 2 en mi `queryset`. 
Gracias.

Este es mi queryset:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(
            Q(chofer__segundo_apellido__icontains=q)|
            Q(chofer__primer_apellido__icontains=q)|
            Q(chofer__nombres__icontains=q)
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno no entendi bien tu pregunta, pero si quieres hacer un filtro que retorne los apellidos de acuerdo a la busqueda puedes hacer esto:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(chofer__primer_apellido__contains=q).filter(chofer__segundo_apellido__contains=q)
```

Lo que hace el anterior query es primero filtra los el primer apellido que contengan el valor de `q`, luego filtra el segundo apellido que contenga el valor de `q` y los une. No podemos confundirlo con lo siguiente:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(chofer__primer_apellido__contains=q, chofer__segundo_apellido__contains=q)
```

La razon es que en este filtro, filtra la busqueda de ambos apellidos que contengan la variable q, osea si tenemos a la persona **pepito ramiro ramiro**, valdria en este queryset, pero si tenemos a la persona **pepito ramiro perez** estaria en el primer queryset.

Avisame si entendiste, [lee esto](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships)